# retrieve only unique records from an ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array of students(students). I need to remove duplicate records from it and get only unique student details. In my console I am getting like

```
students = [
  [#<Student id: 2, admission_no: "2", gender: "m", blood_group: "A">, Wed, 11 Sep 2013, "Student"],
  [#<Student id: 17, admission_no: "17",gender: "m", blood_group: "AB">, Sat, 14 Sep 2013, "Student"],
  [#<Student id: 17, admission_no: "17",gender: "m", blood_group: "AB">, Tue, 17 Sep 2013, "Student"],
  [#<Student id: 2, admission_no: "2",gender: "m">, Tue, 17 Sep 2013, "Student"],
  [#<Student id: 17, admission_no: "17",gender: "m", blood_group: "AB">, Thu, 12 Sep 2013, "Student"]
]
```

I tried using `students = students.uniq`. But it is getting nil values.. Because I am also inserting two more attributes(date  and type i.e last two ones..) retrieved from another table .But I need to display unique students records as well as its type.. How do I do it? Please help.
I am trying to loop an array like this..

```
@mem = []
@tran = Transport.find_all_by_month_and_vehicle(date,vehicle)
    tran.each do |t|
      @mem << [Student.find_by_id(t.mem_id), t.transport_date, vehicle_no] if t.mem_type=="Student"
      @mem << [Employee.find_by_id(t.mem_id), t.transport_date, vehicle_no] if t.mem_type=="Employee"
    end
```

And in the view page I am looping it and displaying it like this

```
@mem.each do |m|
  <tr>
            <td><%= link_to m[0].first_name} %></td>
            <td > <%= m[0].age %></td>
            <td id="date"> m[1] </td>
            <td id="vehicle"> m[2] </td>
  </tr>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Is students the original data? Can you add the code you're using to get `students`

Comment: You probably need to do a joins and group by student id to include the data from the second table... More information please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start in your console. Go to your project root directory and type `rails console`

Now try to find the right join command for your needs.. sometimes this takes trial and error (for me anyway)

I would try something like:

```
Transport.joins(:students).select('students.id, transport_date, vehicle_no, mem_type').group('students.id').where(:mem_type=>"Student")
```

You must have the appropriate associations in your models and foreign keys in your tables.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the better way to do this is by improving your active record query.  However if this is, for whatever reason, what you're stuck with then uniq is the easiest way to go, just add the id to the uniq statement.

```
students = students.uniq(&:id)
```